# How do you organize a large collection of CDs/DVDs?

Tags: dvd, archiving, compact-disc

I have been using a program called myOrganizer, which is quite dated.  Although it is freeware, I think it is a quite out of date program. It does not support tagging, synchronizing, and has very limited searching capability.

So what is your favorite CD/DVD archive organizing tool and why do you think it is superior?

Comment: "What is your favorite" means you're looking to poll, which also should highlight the "community wiki" checkbox when you edit the answer.

Comment: I don't use disks any more. If I need a new OS i just make it a bootable USB and everything is backed up on a HDD.

Answer (score 4):

I keep mine in 5 spindles:

- OS discs
- Game discs for which I don't have an ISO
- Drivers and other software I actually bought
- Blank CDs
- Blank DVDs

No other discs are neccessary.  Ever.

I await your downvotes.

Comment: you asked for it! :) -1

Comment: The question is about some software to keep track of what CD's you have :] Not about the physical storage.

Comment: Slink84 is right. I am trying to figure out what kind of sw is available to keep track of the CD/DVD archive in order to quickly search and organize them "logically" in the SW.

Answer (score 3):

I have never really used a good system other than just a very neat shelf. (and it is the only thing neat here!)

However, I remember seeing an automatic organising system a while ago which I was rather impressed by the [Imation Disk Stakka](http://www.discstakka.com/)-

[image]

That being said, the software let it down a bit, You can find similar versions on Amazon that are stand alone units where you can just type a number and eject a disk.

I was tempted to say - CD, DVD? Old tech! All ISO downloads and/or USB Flash drives.. but thought the above would be better.

Answer (score 2):

[Where Is It?](http://www.whereisit-soft.com/) has always been my choice - nice catalogue-like program, good search capabilities. Unless you're managing thousands of discs, it will in most likeliness, do the job fine. One downside is it's not free.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've used [Smart CD Catalog](http://www.smartcdcatalog.com/) for several years. It's quite good.

Now I'm using my own, but it's still rather flawed :] Sort of an alpha version.

Answer (score 0):

I keep all my cds/dvds in special designed cases for them. I label them usually with a word that summarizes it's content with a sequential number ("Software 001", "Pictures 001", "Complete Albums 0001").

This way, I can use a cd catalog software that searches in all of them when I need to find something specific. If I have for example 30 DVD's with mp3, and search for a band name, it shows in which numbered DVD's are these mp3.

Of course, you need discipline and organization for this approach to work flawlessly. But it's worth. I have DVD's full of old software setups that are indexed this way.

There's a lot of cd catalogs in sourceforge. Or you can use [WhereisIt?](http://www.whereisit-soft.com/), it's not free, but it's a great one (only windows) becaus you can create groups of cds/dvds among other features. It has a good interface as well.

Comment: I suggest you start at 000

Answer (score 0):

call me old-fashioned, but i'm keeping categorized directory listings of my CDs/DVDs. rather basic but it never failed me. no worries about software upgrades or database incopatibilities. **[dirprint](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000772.htm)** is one mighty command (or [**JR Directory Printer**](http://www.spadixbd.com/freetools/jdirprint.htm), if you prefer a GUI).

Answer (score 0):

For Windows: [Collectorz.org](http://www.collectorz.com/)
For Mac: [Delicious Library](http://www.delicious-monster.com/)

Answer (score 0):

See [Gentibus CD](http://www.gentibus.com/).

It works well for all file types and has a good and quick search function (that you can see in the image below):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make ISOs of all my discs. I then store the ISOs on a server in categories under folders such as "software" or "games". Each ISO gets its own folder with a legible name of the content. I sometimes place an info.txt or serial.txt file in this folder containing things such as the install instructions or the serial if required.

The physical discs get placed in a cabinet afterwards in either a "software" pile or "game" pile (no real organization here).

If I need the contents of the disc again in the future I simply create a virtual drive and mount the image.